# using python date in batch file

Tags: python, batch-file

I have following test.bat file:

```
:begin
@echo off

python -c "from datetime import datetime;import sys;sys.stdout.write(datetime.strptime('20200220', '%Y%m%d').replace(day = 1).strftime('%Y%m%d'))"
```

When I run it from cmd, I get:

```
ValueError: time data '20200220' does not match format 'mYd'
```

Please ignore my style of writing, am I missing something?

Comment: Please format the code/data/tracebacks - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: `datetime.datetime.strptime('20200220', '%Y%m%d').replace(day = 1).strftime('%Y%m%d')
'20200201'` works for me in a python shell.

Comment: It seems clear to me that your code is using `Ymd`, and the error is telling you it should be `mYd`! Please delete your question as it is your inability to use the command correctly, and of no use to future readers.

Comment: Thanks wwii, the error is when I call it from cmd

Comment: thanks compo for edit, but that was not the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why but you need to escape the `%`.  This works.

```
...
python -c "from datetime import datetime;import sys;sys.stdout.write(datetime.strptime('20200220', '%%Y%%m%%d').replace(day = 1).strftime('%%Y%%m%%d'))"
```

Answer (score 0):

See the message of error:

```
ValueError: time data '20200220' does not match format 'mYd'
```

2020 is a year 02 month and 20 the day and you try to parse with **mYd**, you need parse with **Ymd**. Set correctly position of the date format.